# How to list all the Node.js modules I have linked with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am looking for a command that will list the names of global modules that I have `npm link`'d to local copies, also listing the local path.

In fact, a list of **all** globally installed modules would be even better, with the `npm link`'d ones **flagged** somehow.

Comment: `npm -g ls` should list all global modules, but I don't know if it lists linked modules

Comment: maintain a "package.json" file for your application

Comment: @CeeAim I have lots of applications with lots of package.jsons, I also have quite a few global modules for other purposes like CLIs, and many are forked and `npm link`'d. I need a way to keep track.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This command is simpler as of npm 7:

```
npm ls --link --global
```

Credit to [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332988/andrew) for finding the `--link` flag

Comment: When was it released?

Comment: October 12th, 2020

Comment: Looks like it might now be `--location=global`

Comment: Both seem to work with npm 8. Is there a deprecation notice somewhere?

Answer (score 380):

To list all globally linked modules, this works (documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls):

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 --link=true
```

I had to update the version of npm on my machine first, though:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: The 1st one works w/o `--link=true`. My environment: Win10, NVM=1.1.7, current Node= 8.14.0

Comment: and to remove one that's listed: `npm unlink <package> -g`

Comment: @Jeb50 that makes sense, because linked packages are installed globally.

Comment: With newer npm versions you can shorten this to `npm ls -g --link`

Answer (score 73):

Did you try just listing the `node_modules` directory contents (e.g., `ls -l node_modules | grep ^l`)? They're normal symbolic links.

If you really need to find *all* symbolic links, you could try something like `find / -type d -name "node_modules" 2>/dev/null | xargs -I{} find {} -type l -maxdepth 1 | xargs ls -l`.

Comment: Doesn't work with locally linked namespaced modules (@namespace/moduleName). A brutal solution might be: `( ls -l node_modules ; ls -l node_modules/@* ) | grep ^l`

Comment: This solution doesn't work on Windows (nor do any other solutions).

Comment: @MicahZoltu It will work on Windows if you use the Git bash terminal

Comment: For @scoped packages, just add -R to the ls command: `ls -l -R ./node_modules | grep ^l`

Answer (score 24):

A better alternative to parsing `ls` is to use `find` like this:

```
find . -type l
```

You can use `-maxdepth 1` to only process the first directory level:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

You can use `-ls` for additional information.

For instance, for finding Node.js modules that are npm linked:

```
find node_modules -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls
```

**Here's [an article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) why parsing `ls` is not the best idea**.

Comment: This was useful for me—thanks :) Gist: https://gist.github.com/ryanve/5e28670dc459a4f83955b20f31b3a9e0

Answer (score 14):

If you want a nice colored output from `npm list`, you may like:

```
\ls -F node_modules | sed -n 's/@$//p' | xargs npm ls -g --depth 0
```

which gives in my current playground directory:

```
+-- color@0.11.1
+-- grunt@0.4.5
+-- http-server@0.8.5
+-- jsdom@8.0.2
+-- jsonfile@2.2.3
+-- underscore@1.8.3
+-- xmlserializer@0.3.3
`-- zombie@4.2.1
```

It makes a few assumptions, but it should work in most cases, or be easy to adapt with the explanations below.

- use `\ls` to bypass possible aliases on your `ls` command
- the `-F` option adds an '@' indicator for links
- the `sed` command selects those links and removes the indicator
- the `xargs` part passes previous output as arguments to `npm ...`
- `npm` is invoked with

  - `list` or `ls` to list modules with versions
  - replace with `ll` to get details about each listed module.
  - `-g` for the global modules and
  - `--depth 0` for a shallow listing (optional)
  - `--long false` (default with 'list').

*Issue:* for some reason *npm* gives extraneous entries for me at the moment (non colored). They would be those I had "*npm unlink*"ed.

For "*a list of all globally installed modules*" in current npm path, you just do

```
npm list -g
```

For further needs you may want to have a look at

```
npm help folders
```

You cannot follow symlinks backwards unless you scan your whole filesystem and (then that's not a npm specific question).

For quickly finding files and directories by name, I use `locate` which works on an index rebuilt usually once a day.

```
locate '*/node_modules'
```

and start working from there (you may want to refine the search with `--regexp` option.

Comment: I use without `-g` to get my local/nearest transient dependency links.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
find `npm root -g` -maxdepth 2 -type l
```

to show global links, including namespaced packages.

[Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933955/how-to-list-all-the-node-js-modules-i-have-linked-with-npm/48593067#48593067) works some of the time:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 --link=true
```

But it blew up on peer dependency errors for me on some occasions.

Answer (score 4):

I made a Node.js module, *[symlinked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/symlinked)*, that uses `fs` to check for symbolic links made by `npm link` or otherwise.

```
var symlinked = require("symlinked")

console.log(symlinked.names())
```

Comment: Would be really sweet if you added a CLI executable for this, especially in light of https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b. Most use cases for needing to find symlinked packages are from CLI.

Comment: couldn't detect any links for some reason :(

Comment: @cchamberlain can you point me to good CLI tool to model the API after? Or definitely feel free to contribute a cli command to https://github.com/ryanve/symlinked :)

Comment: @JacopKane Are you able to post an issue on https://github.com/ryanve/symlinked/issues/new with details?

Comment: @ryanve - done https://github.com/ryanve/symlinked/pull/1 - I also added scoped packages support since that wasn't working. Kudos on the simple structure! :)

Answer (score 4):

I found this question after I also wrote my own tool, and here it is for completeness: [npm-list-linked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-list-linked).

It will recursively follow all linked packages down in the hierarchy as well. At my work we sometimes may have `npm link` 2-3 levels deep and this way you can see exactly which are local and which ones are not. It avoids surprises.

```
npm-list-linked
```

Output:

```
Linked packages in /home/user/projects/some-project/
    @prefix/package 0.2.7
        other-package 0.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I see myself and others having this same question a lot. I wrote a small CLI for myself called `link-status` to display this info, and it may help others out too! Check it out [here!](https://github.com/danmakenoise/link-status)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can just look at the directory:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

You should see any of the symbolic linked libraries listed there, along side any global library installs.