# Custom Angular Directive: NullInjectorError:StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatInput -> ElementRef]

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Angular app is failing to compile due to error below. I am not sure why. I did just upgrade to Angular 8 but I have updated and reinstalled the Material dependencies.

```
NullInjectorError:StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatInput -> ElementRef]: 
 StaticInjectorError(Platform: core) [MatInput -> ElementRef]: 
   NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
```

**Update**

Okay, this apparently due to a directive I have created. If I remove the reference to the directive then the error is resolved. There must an injection issue in my directive.

Does the file location mess up angular initial configurations? For instance, the command line generates a service in the app root directory. I have moved my services to a 'services' folder. Would this be an issue?

This is the tutorial I used to build this directive.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-implement-feature-flags/

**./app.component.html** - this is were I invoke the directive

```
<div>
  <app-compliance-review [myRemoveIfFeatureOff]="'compliancerev'" compliancerev="true"></app-compliance-review>
</div>
```

**directives/remove-if-feature-off.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FeatureFlagService } from '../services/feature-flag.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myRemoveIfFeatureOff]'
})
export class MyRemoveIfFeatureOffDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('myRemoveIfFeatureOff') featureName: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
              private featureFlagService: FeatureFlagService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.featureFlagService.featureOff(this.featureName)) {
      this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement);
    }
  }
}
```

**services/feature-flag.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FeatureFlagService {

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){}

  featureOff(featureName: string) {
    // Read the value from the root element
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.hasOwnProperty(featureName)) {
      let sFlag: string = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute(featureName);
      let bFlag: boolean = (sFlag =="true");
      return !bFlag;
    }
    return true; // if feature not found, default to turned off
  }

  featureOn(featureName: string) {
    return !this.featureOff(featureName);
  }
}
```

**StackTrace:**
[image: Error Stack Trace]

Comment: I've had problems with the platform core and providers when using `npm link`. Are any of your node modules linked?

Comment: @Reactgular, I haven't linked any modules myself. How do I double check this?

Comment: You'd remember if you did, but here's help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933955/easy-way-to-list-node-modules-i-have-npm-linked

Comment: try changing `private el: ElementRef` too `private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>`. Not sure if that will help.

Comment: No linking on the node_modules.

Comment: You can't inject ElementRef to an Angular service. ElementRef can be injected in directives and components because they are associated with a single element in the DOM. Services are not associated with any given element, so injecting ElementRef will fail. Instead, you'll need to pass the ElementRef as a parameter to the service function if it's needed.

Comment: @AlexK brining the heat! That's it. I removed the ElementRef reference and we're up and running. If you want to create an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inject `ElementRef` to an Angular service.

`ElementRef` can be injected in directives and components because they are associated with a single element in the DOM. Services are not associated with any given element, so injecting `ElementRef` will fail.

If you need to access an `ElementRef` instance from a service function, you'll need to pass the reference as a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably you are not importing `MatInputModule` into module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatInputModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I am importing this module in my root module. I have provided an updated on my issue.